# Mobile Broadband Not Enabling

Tags: networking, 13.04, network-manager, mobile-broadband

I am using a Qualcom Broadband (EVDO) dongle on Ubuntu 13.04. I have used this dongle well for a number of days on Ubuntu 13.04 but recently I had to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 but when I try to use the dongle the option for Enable Mobile Broadband keeps unchecking itself and I get a "not enabled" as the name of my connection. After a few tries of checking the Enable Mobile Broadband option I get this  error :

"Creating Object path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6 failed in libnm-glib"

Comment: I suggest you upgrade to 14.04 LTS. 13.04 is past EOL. See support schedule [here] (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: How does an EOL Ubuntu release related question become off-topic here? Is this a "canonical support forum" or an open community forum?

Comment: @Sri you said "This question could be closed as "duplicate"".  Duplicate of what?.  Also EOL release are off-topic, because When an Ubuntu release reaches its “end of life” it receives no further maintenance updates, including critical security upgrades.

Comment: New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: @Mitch the help page only "recommends" to "avoid" - it's not a hard and fast rule. I believe community forums and OSS exist because proprietary product companies behave like this, putting off novice users, putting limits etc. We should not behave like Apple or Microsoft! In fact, I landed on this question because I was searching for a similar issue, and my Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS with the latest updates of 2 or 3 days back.